# How can you demangle QStringList in Qt6, so it does not convert to "QList<QString>"?

Tags: c++, typename, typeid, qt6, demangler

I have been using this function for quite some time in Qt5:

```cpp
static QString demangle( const QString &name )
{
    int status;
    std::unique_ptr< char, void(*)( void* ) > res (
        abi::__cxa_demangle( name.toLatin1(), nullptr, nullptr, &status ), std::free );
    return { ( status == 0 ) ? QLatin1String( res.get() ) : name };
}
```

Since starting to use Qt6,

```cpp
ct_Halt( demangle(typeid (QStringList).name() ), demangle(typeid (QList<QString>).name() ) );
```

now produces

```cpp
QString demangle(typeid (QStringList).name() )
"QList<QString>" // This used to produce QStringList in Qt5

QString demangle(typeid (QList<QString>).name() )
"QList<QString>"
```

This little annoyance has broken a library that I created. Its not a big deal but I'd like to know if the demangle function can be "fixed" to accurately reflect the typename.

Comment: In Qt6, [`QStringList` is an alias of `QList<QString>`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/6.0/src/corelib/tools/qcontainerfwd.h#L65), so they are exactly the same type. There is no way to distinguish between them.

Comment: I suspected that was the case. I am kind of surprised though and am curious how they did that, considering there are some QStringList specific functions, like "replaceInStrings"

Comment: @Anon why is that surprising? `QStringList` is still a type. Just because it now aliases another type doesn't mean it can't still be used as itself. The only real issue would be if there were a function with a `QList<QString>` argument, and an *overloaded* function using the same arguments except for `QStringList` instead. That would be ambiguous. Otherwise, you shouldn't need to concern yourself with how `QStringList` is *implemented*, as long as its interface is consistent with what you are expecting.